# canvas function imageObj onload in slower and doesnt return anything

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, canvas

I have created a function on javascript and google maps for using a external icon, and redraw it using html5 canvas, however, cause of loading icon, when I use the **imageObj.onload**, function sont return anything, then I remove that function and sent the result anyway, but it is not the right form on working with icons and canvas
My code is

```
function getIconMarker(course, speed){
        course = parseFloat (course) * 0.01745327777;
        if (parseInt(speed) != 0) {
            imageIcon = '{% static "markers/onmove.gif" %}';
        } else {
            imageIcon = '{% static "markers/onstop.png" %}';
        }
        var elemento = document.createElement("canvas");
        elemento.width = 80;
        elemento.height = 80;
        if(elemento && elemento.getContext){
            var context = elemento.getContext('2d');
            if(context){
                var imageObj = new Image();
                imageObj.src = imageIcon;
                //imageObj.onload = function(){
                    //console.debug('image loaded');
                    context.save();
                    context.translate(imageObj.width, imageObj.height);
                    context.rotate(course);
                    context.drawImage(imageObj, -(imageObj.width/2), -(imageObj.height/2));
                    context.restore();
                    //console.debug(elemento.toDataURL());
                    return elemento.toDataURL();
                //} 
                console.debug('image no loaded');
            }
            console.debug('no context created');
        }
        console.debug('no context enblaed');
        //return imageIcon;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image loading is async so you will *have* to chain calls. One way of doing this is to make a call-chain using events.

A call-chain is started with a function, when done it calls the next function in the chain, when done the next and so forth.

The major difference is that you divide your code in functions instead of having one single global function.

A typical synchronous code can look like this:

```
Start:
result = doSomething()
result = doSomethingElse()
result = calc something
result = andDoSomeMore()
...
Finished!
```

This works fine because the next function won't be called before the current function has finished.

While an asynchronous approach will look like this:

```
function doSomething()           then call doSomethingElse(result)
function doSomethingElse(result) then call calc function(result)
function calcSomething(result)   calc something, call andDoSomeMore(result)
function andDoSomeMore(result)   Finished!

Start: doSomething()
```

The only thing happening in the global context with the asynchronous approach is to start the first part of the chain as we have to wait for something to finish before we can continue. We will know when to continue when we receive an event inside the function. We do not handle any result from aync functions as we do in the sync approach. Async functions can't *return* any data. They need to *pass on* the data as an argument to the next function that is called when an event occur with the data needed.

The global context is basically and generally speaking only for holding the functions and variables we need for our chain and to start it.

For example, you can modify your function to take call-backs, one for success and one for error. When the image load event is finished it will invoke those functions which will go to the next step in your chain:

```
function getIconMarker(course, speed, callback, callbackError){
    // other code snipped...

    if(elemento && elemento.getContext){
        var context = elemento.getContext('2d');
        if(context){
            var imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.onload = function(){
                console.debug('image loaded');
                context.save();
                context.translate(imageObj.width, imageObj.height);
                context.rotate(course);
                context.drawImage(imageObj, -(imageObj.width/2), -(imageObj.height/2));
                context.restore();

                //use a callback to trigger next function with image as argument
                callback(elemento.toDataURL());
            }
            imageObj.onerror = callbackError;
            imageObj.src = imageIcon; // start loading image and return (void)
        }
    }
}
```

As now we can pass on the data we do that as an argument to the function. The callback functions can look like this:

```
function callbackSuccess(dataUri) {
    // we got an image
    //perform next step, upload etc.
    //...
}
```

For the error handler (which could be common in typical scenarios) - (give it a more logic name, ie. the name that fits the next step), example:

```
function callbackError(errorEvent) {
    console.log(errorEvent);
    alert('An error occurred loading an image');
}
```

It all works by calling:

```
getIconMarker(course, speed, callbackSuccsess, callbackError);
```

`getIconMarker` will return immediately but it will, when ready, pass on the data to the next function.

Comment: Tanks a lot for the answer, I am trying it, probably I have some issues, I hope you could give a hand on probable issues. Thanks a lot

Comment: What I am doing is a function call on setting icon like "imageIcon = getIconMarker(positions[i].course, positions[i].speed);" I  think what I must to do is something like "getIconMarker(course, speed, callbackSuccsess, callbackError);", however, I also think I must send the marker id for the success callback, is it ok?

Comment: @Carlos that should be fine. You can also construct an object/array with all settings you need for the next call and pass that in as a single argument.

Answer (score -2):

The toDataURL function of the canvas is not meant for images.
One cannot draw an image on canvas and convert it to URL using the toDataURL function.
Only the elements like rectangle,line and other shaped drawn on the canvas can be converted to URL data with the function toDataURL. I guess you have to find an other way.

Comment: You are wrong sir. The toDataURL method can be used for images drawn on canvas too. The only problem is the same origin policy which, for security reasons, only allows draw images from the same domain as the page where the canvas appears. If a canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data, toDataURL will fail.